# How to attach an extra volume in multiple running deployments without editing every deployment?

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volume-claims

Use Case:

We have scenario where we want to attach an extra volume in multiple running deployments without editing every deployment.

We'd want to edit in one place and the changes should reflect in every deployment.

We have looked into dynamic volume provisioning.

Answer (score 0):

You may dynamically provision volumes via a storage class object which includes a provisioner to be described. So a storage class would provision your volumes.

(Here I assume that you also want a pvc to be attached to your deployments automatically)
Any in-tree or out-of-tree storage provisioners provision based on the persistentvolumeclaim created for each deployment. (read more [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/design-proposals-archive/blob/main/storage/volume-provisioning.md) on in-tree and out-of-tree provisioner's design).

So your question of how to do this seems incomplete or mis-represented. Because you technically can attach a volume to each deployment dynamically,  by going deployment by deployment creating claims.

Deployments allow you to not have to go pod by pod, so atleast that is made available.

I too am new to this, so I apologize for making assumptions that may have skewed my answer.

TLDR: You can use storage class to create volumes. You still need to make the PVC on each deployment.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).